# Doing calculations with the ATR || PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So I was trying to do calculations with this value from the ATR:
[image]

But for some reason, I keep doing calculations with a different number.

I want to do this:

```
realBodyMidpoint1   = realBodyMidpoint + ATR_Handle
realBodyMidpoint2   = realBodyMidpoint - ATR_Handle
...
plot(realBodyMidpoint1, title="TP Up", color=#0bf86e7e, offset = 1)
plot(realBodyMidpoint2, title="TP Low", color=#0bf86e7e, offset = 1)
```

The ATR_Handle holds the ATR value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question here? What is wrong?

Comment: The ATR_Handle should hold the ATR value, it doesn't right now, kind of messed up the structure of that sentence.

Comment: How do you calculate the `ATR_Handle`? Update your question with a compilable code example.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for wanting to help!